# Making recyclerview fill entire page

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a page that has a custom recyclerview. I want items I add to the recyclerview to pop up in a list. App was working just fine before I updated my AppCompact library. But essentially, I had anchored my FAB to a Coordinator layout, but I got an IllegalStateException and to resolve that, I had to anchor it to one of the Coordinator layout's children. I picked the recyclerview. But the problem now is that the recycler view does not fill the entire page. It only shows one item (I can scroll through them) but they only take up the space of one - like viewing one at a time. How do I make the layout work like it did before the update?

This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/base_toolbar"/>-->
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reminderEmptyView"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/empty_view_bg"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="Nothing added yet"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <!--<include layout="@layout/base_toolbar"/>-->


        <!--</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>-->


        <apps.todo.Utility.RecyclerViewEmptySupport
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/toDoRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionBut
```

Comment: `CoordinatorLayout` should always be at the top level of the view hierarchy, remove the outer LinearLayout.

Comment: can you also add your recycle view item layout

Comment: Yeah the layout of your item is likely `match_parent` for `android:layout_height` based on the description and looking at the layout with the `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need that parent LinearLayout.
Just copy

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

These into your CoordinatorLayout.

Then remove `gravity` from your Coordinator Layout and change your FloatingActionButton to:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
   android:id="@+id/addToDoItemFAB"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="16dp"
   android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>
```

This fixes the connection between your RecyclerView and FAB.

This Blog post may help you as well: https://android.jlelse.eu/coordinatorlayout-basic-8040c74cf426

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reminderEmptyView"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/empty_view_bg"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="Nothing added yet"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <apps.rtkay.pookiev2.todo.Utility.RecyclerViewEmptySupport
            android:id="@+id/toDoRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/addToDoItemFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```